# dynamics length html and angular js

Tags: html, angularjs

I have to check the extension of my emails example: test.tes@test.com, "com" must not exceed 20char

my code in html:

```
    <input
     .................
     ng-model = "contactemail.coordonnee.value"
     ng-change = "filterExtension(contactemail.coordonnee.value);"
     my-maxlength = {{maxlength}}
 </ Td>
```

my angular code js:

```
$ scope.filterExtension = function (email) {

   var words = email.split ('.');
   if (words [words.length - 1] .length> = 2) {
      $scope.$parent.$parent.maxlength = email.length;
   } else {
     $ $ $ Parent scope parent.maxlength = 100000;..}

   return $scope.$parent.$parent.maxlength;
 };
```

the user must insert an email with an extension of 20 characters

**Expected result**: as soon as the extension exceeds 20 characters we can not write in the input

**Result obtained**: the user can still write in the input

i need help or another solution 
thank's

Comment: why are you doing this:`$ scope. $ parent. $ parent.maxlength = email.length;` if you know maxlength has to be 20 just add it to HTML

Comment: You have several ways to do it. The best ones are mainly two: 1) use `ng-pattern` 2) create your own custom validator

Comment: You’re code will fail if the email has more dots in it

Comment: @nircraft my maxlength is dynamic and != 20